# How to transfer lumber cut with odd angles

Tags: wood, woodworking, cutting, lumber

I am interested in learning this craftsmanship /technique:

[image]

Look like the piece of lumber in between has perfect cut to match the angles.

How did they transfer the cut dimension? Is there a tool for that?

I was thinking about using paper cardboard templates but even so, it's not perfectly lined up like the photo.

Comment: Could use a t-bevel or if one is skilled, it could be scribed

Comment: "scribed" is nearly impossible as you can see the truss running toward the top with narrower angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried a few cuts like this and got one of the crazy devices shown below. It's a "multi angle measuring ruler". Even if you get the angles right, you still have to cut the wood accurately and that requires a good miter saw, and even then, be prepared to do it a few times to get the saw set just right. This is an art and it takes a lot of practice It's not as easy as Norm makes it look on "this old house'. Good luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The T bevel gauge would be a good assist in some of the cutting, but I would use thin strips of wood, say about 1 1/2" X 1/8" thick and hot glue the corners. I would not use anything thicker for it would change the length of the finished piece. No need to cut all the way into the corners, the straight lines could be simply projected to intersect.

The bevel gauge would determine the set of the bevel of the saw, while the "template" determines the angles and length.